# I get a wrong result if I copy the return value of a function to another register instead of r1, why?

Tags: linux, assembly, arm, printf, calling-convention

I am trying to print `do_something`'s return value that is stored in r0. After `bl do_something` statement, if a copy r0 in r1 the output is correct (`8`). But if a copy r0 in r2, the output is incorrect, why?

```
    .global  main
    .extern abs
    .extern printf

    .text
output_str:
    .ascii     "The answer is %d\n\0"

    .align 4
diffofsums:
    push {r4, r5, lr}
    add r4, r0, r1  ;r4 = f - g
    add r5, r2, r3  ;r5 = h - i
    sub r0, r4, r5  ;r0 = result = r4 - r5
    pop {r4, r5, pc}
    bx lr

main:
    push {ip, lr}
    mov r0, #2
    mov r1, #3
    mov r2, #4
    mov r3, #5
    bl diffofsums
    mov r2, r0          ;incorrect output! (correct output when I write mov r1, r0)
    ldr r0, =output_str
    bl printf
    mov r0, #0
    pop {ip, pc}
```

Maybe it's a `printf` problem? I don't quite understand how printing works in ARM Assembly.

Comment: Because the second argument goes into `r1` according to the calling convention. That is where `printf` will look for it. How do you expect it to know where your number is? There needs to be a convention so you put things where the callee expects them. That means `r0` has the first argument which is the format string and `r1` has the second argument which is the first item to be printed.

Comment: Yes this! Are you referring to printf arguments? I don't understand how many arguments the printf function has. Can you explain it to me?

Comment: Do you know C? `printf` is a C standard library function.

Comment: Yes, I got confused because English is not my mother tongue. So I understood that it is equivalent to the statement printf(""The answer is %d\n\0", result) where the argument result contains the value of r1 according to ARM conventions

Comment: @abstract42 Yes, correct.  The format string is in `r0`, the argument to the right of it in `r1`, and so on.

Comment: `printf` is working similar to `diffofsums`: parameters are passed in sequential register numbers. Also, the caller owns the parameter registers, so can destroy them at will; This means there no need for `r4` and `r5` — `diffofsums: add r0,r0,r1; add r1,r2,r3; sub r0,r0,r1; bx lr`

Comment: And if you `pop` into the `pc` the function is over, that `bx lr` following will never execute (though is harmless)

Comment: Ok, I finally understand it